# SSRS 2008 Report with a link which opens an attachment

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Is there a way to develop a SSRS report with a link which opens an attachment(PDF,DOC,DWG,JPEG etc) which is stored in the server database.

Answer (score 2):

The action tab in the text box properties is probably going to be the most helpful to you.  In there you can have it go to another report which could contain the document you want or if you have it stored in some URL, that works as well.  The action happens when they click on the text box.